# SQL 1/count returning no row

Tags: sql

```
select e_id, 1/count(e_id)as occur from projectregistary2 group by e_id
```

in above query if occur is 3 then it should return 0.33 but it return no value column like below

```
E_ID    OCCUR
1       1
```

Comment: huh?  Please read [ask]

Comment: Can you show us a SQL Fiddle of the problem? What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your database may be doing integer division.  I would recommend:

```
select e_id, 1.0 / nullif(count(e_id), 0) as occur
from projectregistary2
group by e_id;
```

The `nullif()` prevents divide-by-zero, which can occur when you are counting an expression (if `e_id` is `NULL`).  You might want:

```
select e_id, 1.0 / count(*) as occur
from projectregistary2
group by e_id;
```